# UI is not updating after state changes

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
function App() {
    const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState(sampleRecipes)
    function handleAddRecipe() {
        const newRecipe = {
            id: uuidv4(),
            name: "Banana Shake",
            servings: 1,
            cooktime: "0.5",
            instructions: "1. Put suger into cut bananas\n2. Blend it",
            ingredients: [
                {
                    id: uuidv4(),
                    name: 'sugar',
                    amount: '2 tbs'
                }
            ]
        }
        console.log([...recipes, newRecipe])
        setRecipes([...recipes, newRecipe])
    }

    function handleDeleteRecipe(id) {
        const filteredRecipes = recipes.filter(recipe => recipe.id !== id);
        console.log(filteredRecipes)
        setRecipes(filteredRecipes)
    }

    return (
        <RecipeList recipes={sampleRecipes} 
            handleAddRecipe={handleAddRecipe} 
            handleDeleteRecipe={handleDeleteRecipe}
        />
    )
}
```

Here I am tring to add a new recipe to the list by updated state using useState hook.
Default value of state is 'sampleRecipes' which an array of objects.
I have checked that the state of the recipes is changed but the UI is not updated.
Is there anything wrong using an array for state?

Comment: You passing `recipes={sampleRecipes}` and not `recipes` state, the UI don't suppose to change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing in the constant `sampleRecipes` instead of the state `recipes` to your list.

Comment: Rookie mistake. Thanks for the help.